# How do i find the last used column in a row? C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel sheet that I am reading. it contains multiple rows (No headers) each row containing a different number of populated columns.
i.e. row 1 has data in the first three columns.
row 2 has data in the first 140 columns.
row 3 has data in the first 32 columns. etc etc.

If I need to find out how many columns row 2 uses (How many contain data), how would I start.

I am teaching myself c sharp at the moment and am jargon illiterate, so please be as "Layman" as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit ------------------------

Had a quick look through some bookmarks and have a rough idea of the code i used to get the row number containing the columns i need to count. (i cant test as i don't have VS installed at home. so dont take this as gospel, but it seems "approximately" correct, sorry.)

```
private static Excel.Application HCObjApp = null;
private static Excel.Workbook HCBook = null; 
private static Excel.Worksheet HCSheet = null;

XLApp = new Excel.Application();
HCBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(@"WBPATH\WB.exe");
HCSheet = HCBook.Sheets[1];
lastRow = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row; 

Excel.Range range = HCSheet.Columns["A", Type.Missing];

currentFind = range.Find("Australia",HCSheet.Cells[lastrow, 1]);
```

from here i need to find the number of used columns in row CurrentFind.

--------------------Edit--------------------------------
Finally back in the office, This was the code i had to find the row number;

```
        EHObjApp.Visible = true;

        string ColumnHeader = ResourceDetails.ResourceHolder("Root") + ResourceDetails.ResourceHolder("ResourceFolder") + ResourceDetails.ResourceHolder("ColumnHeaders");
        HCBook = EHObjApp.Workbooks.Open(ColumnHeader);
        HCSheet = HCBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        InputBook = EHObjApp.Workbooks.Open(ResourceDetails.ResourceHolder("Root") + @"\Sales\Output\Zoho_Upload\ZOHOSales.xlsx");
        InputSheet = InputBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        long ExRownumber = HCSheet.Range["A:A"].Find("SalesAustralia").Row + 1;
        Range NewColumns = InputSheet.Range["A1:A" + InputSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count];
```

With Many thanks to @Hambone i found the solution (more accurately i found 0.1% of the solution. Hambone found the rest);

```
            Excel.Range ur = HCSheet.UsedRange;
            Excel.Range r = HCSheet.Cells[ExRownumber, ur.Columns.Count +1];
            r = r.Columns.End[Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft];
//            r = r.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
            long ExistingColumns = r.Column;


            MessageBox.Show(lastCol.ToString());
```

This will find the last used column in the row.

You guys have been an amazing help!

Thank you

----------Addition---------------
When finding the smaller column numbers, i.e. rows of 30 or 31 columns etc, this worked fine. I ran into an issue when trying to find the larger numbers, i.e. rows of 140 columns. 
Changing xlToLeft back to xlUp solved this issue.

Thought i would add this in for anyone that requires this solution in the future.

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to open the sheet and read from it?

Comment: I can, but not until monday. its on my work computer.

Comment: you can convert the data into a Datatable and check it that way.. or you can get a parser there are some free tools on line also do a stackoverflow search on ConvertExcel2DataTable I think I have posted a nice solution a while back. I am driving now so can't look for it.. using speech to text..woowho

Comment: This is not a good project to work on for teaching yourself C#  as this requires you to use COM InterOp, which is slow and if not coded correctly, will cause memory leaks. Instead, you should write this as VBA embedded directly into the .xlsx file.

Comment: @PatrickHofman What are you talking about? C# runs in the .NET CLR and VBA runs agains the VBA scripting engine (not .NET). Entirely different codebases and APIs.

Comment: What do you mean "still"? Of course the back end is COM. That's exactly what I'm trying to point out. Using .NET to access COM requires COM InterOp, which requires additional steps to be taken for memory clean up from .NET that don't have to be addressed in VBA. Doing this work in VBA circumvents all that, which was my point.

Comment: Don't you want to use dynamic types when working with Excel?

Comment: I don't think you would. I don't think that using them would add any value and you'd still have to release all the individual objects created (Sheets, Cells, Ranges, etc.) explicitly, but with dynamic types, you would lose intellisense, so the API would have to be known by the programmer.  All this is avoided by simply writing the solution in VBA.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - I don't think you understand the special problems working with COM InterOp introduces into a .NET application in general and how working with Excel's API in .NET (specifically) adds to those problems. Every single object instance created must be explicitly destroyed (setting object to null) in .NET and Marshall.ReleaseComObject(obj) must also be called as well. Since Excel's API has many methods that implicitly return a new object instance, it's very easy to wind up with instances that you are not aware of and forget to release them.  NONE of this applies when working in VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this technique used in VBA to find the last row in a range, and it ports pretty nicely to C#:

```
Excel.Range ur = HCSheet.UsedRange;

Excel.Range r = HCSheet.Cells[2, ur.Columns.Count];
r = r.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft);
```

The value of `r` at this point will be the last populated cell in row 2.  To get a row other than 2, you would simply change the first parameter in the `.Cells` indexer.

To prove it works, you can do something like this:

```
r.Value = "Gotcha";
```

To find the last column number, which I think was your question:

```
int lastCol = r.Column;
```

Comment: can't test until Monday when i get back to work, but from my VERY basic knowledge of C# and "ok" knowledge of VBA, this does look promising. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code was almost there. Was an excellent jumping off point though. Changed xlup to xlToLeft and int LastCol = r.columns.count to r.Column. Works fantastically now. I knew it shouldnt be overly difficult. :)

Answer (score 0):

This my simplicity function get last used row and col with Excel Package

```
public int GetLastUsedRow(ExcelWorksheet sheet)
        {
            if (sheet.Dimension == null) { return 0; } // In case of a blank sheet
            var row = sheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            while (row >= 1)
            {
                var range = sheet.Cells[row, 1, row, sheet.Dimension.End.Column];
                if (range.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text)))
                {
                    break;
                }
                row--;
            }
            return row;
        }
        public int GetLastUsedColumn(ExcelWorksheet sheet)
        {
            int count=0;
            int i = 1;
            while(sheet.Cells[1, i].Value != null)
            {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Excel automation is a ambitious endeavor for just starting with any .NET languages. Upfront, many examples on the web don't take into consideration properly releasing memory and will resort to using calls to the garbage collector when not needed. In the example code below the method UsedRowsColumns does not need any calls to the garbage collector simply because I followed what I call the [two dot rule](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/08/06/vb-net-two-dot-rule-when-working-with-office-applications-2/) (which 99.99 percent of the time releases all object, but as you will see not always). You will note clicking on kevininstructor on that page for the two dot rule will fail, I changed it as I changed to [kareninstructor](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/kareninstructor/).

- The classes shown below, I would test them and if they suit your needs place them into a class project so if you want to use this code in other projects you simply add a reference to those projects instead of copying code from project to project.
- The Console.WriteLine in button1 uses VS2015 syntax, if using a lower version then adjustments such as this would be needed Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",....

Unlike UsedRowsColumns method, LastColumnForRow (which should answer your question) must do some extra work in that the garbage collector needs to be called but not in the same method so I setup the class to have a method CallGarbageCollector which after making the call to LastColumnForRow I call this to release the Range xlColumns which would not release even when doing the two dot rule.

Form code to test, button1 makes a call to get the last column for row 2.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace UsedRowsCols
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private string fileName = Path.Combine(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Demo.xlsx");
        private string sheetName = "Sheet1";
        /// <summary>
        /// Get last row and last column for a worksheet.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExcelUsed eu = new ExcelUsed();
            ExcelLast results = eu.UsedRowsColumns(fileName, sheetName);
            // send results to Visual Studio Output window
            Console.WriteLine($"{results.Row} {results.Column}");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get last used column for a specific row
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExcelUsed eu = new ExcelUsed();
            try
            {
                int results = eu.LastColumnForRow(fileName, sheetName,2);
                // send results to Visual Studio Output window
                Console.WriteLine(results);
            }
            finally
            {
                eu.CallGarbageCollector();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class responsible for obtaining used column in button1 above and used rows and columns in button2 above.

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace UsedRowsCols
{
    public class ExcelUsed
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get last used column for a row
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        /// <param name="sheetName"></param>
        /// <param name="row"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int LastColumnForRow(string fileName, string sheetName, int row)
        {
            int lastColumn = -1;

            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                Excel.Application xlApp = null;
                Excel.Workbooks xlWorkBooks = null;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
                Excel.Sheets xlWorkSheets = null;

                xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

                xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
                xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(fileName);

                xlApp.Visible = false;

                xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets;

                for (int x = 1; x <= xlWorkSheets.Count; x++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkSheets[x];

                    if (xlWorkSheet.Name == sheetName)
                    {
                        Excel.Range xlCells = null;
                        xlCells = xlWorkSheet.Cells;

                        Excel.Range workRange = xlCells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);

                        Excel.Range xlColumns = xlWorkSheet.Columns;

                        int count = xlColumns.Count;

                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlColumns);
                        xlColumns = null;

                        Excel.Range xlLastRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, count];
                        Excel.Range xlDirRange = xlLastRange.End[Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft];

                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlLastRange);
                        xlLastRange = null;

                        lastColumn = xlDirRange.Column;
                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlDirRange);
                        xlDirRange = null;

                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workRange);
                        workRange = null;

                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlCells);
                        xlCells = null;

                        break;
                    }

                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
                    xlWorkSheet = null;

                }

                xlWorkBook.Close();
                xlApp.UserControl = true;
                xlApp.Quit();

                Release(xlWorkSheets);
                Release(xlWorkSheet);
                Release(xlWorkBook);
                Release(xlWorkBooks);
                Release(xlApp);

                return lastColumn;

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("'" + fileName + "' not found.");
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">file to get information form</param>
        /// <param name="sheetName">valid sheet name to get last row and column</param>
        /// <returns>ExcelLast</returns>
        public ExcelLast UsedRowsColumns(string fileName, string sheetName)
        {

            int RowsUsed = -1;
            int ColsUsed = -1;

            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                Excel.Application xlApp = null;
                Excel.Workbooks xlWorkBooks = null;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
                Excel.Sheets xlWorkSheets = null;

                xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

                xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
                xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(fileName);

                xlApp.Visible = false;

                xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets;

                for (int x = 1; x <= xlWorkSheets.Count; x++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkSheets[x];

                    if (xlWorkSheet.Name == sheetName)
                    {
                        Excel.Range xlCells = null;
                        xlCells = xlWorkSheet.Cells;

                        Excel.Range workRange = xlCells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);

                        RowsUsed = workRange.Row;
                        ColsUsed = workRange.Column;

                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workRange);
                        workRange = null;


                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlCells);
                        xlCells = null;

                        break;
                    }

                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
                    xlWorkSheet = null;

                }

                xlWorkBook.Close();
                xlApp.UserControl = true;
                xlApp.Quit();


                Release(xlWorkSheets);
                Release(xlWorkSheet);
                Release(xlWorkBook);
                Release(xlWorkBooks);
                Release(xlApp);

                return new ExcelLast() { Row = RowsUsed, Column = ColsUsed };

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("'" + fileName + "' not found.");
            }
        }
        public void CallGarbageCollector()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        }
        private void Release(object sender)
        {
            try
            {
                if (sender != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sender);
                    sender = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                sender = null;
            }
        }
    }
    public class ExcelLast
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Last used row in specific sheet
        /// </summary>
        public int Row { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Last used column in specific sheet
        /// </summary>
        public int Column { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling GC.Collect is never advisable. It's really only ever used in extreme scenarios that often involve reflection. The correct way to work with COM InterOp is to explicitly manage your COM instances, set them to null when done with them and then call Marshal.RelaseComObject(obj).  GC.anything should be avoided at all costs because you actually can slow down the application when calling any GC method (this is because the GC will now run in the same thread as your app and not its own thread as it normally does).

Comment: @scott, I agree that GC is not advisable but as I said, 99.99 percent of the time I have never used GC, matter of fact I have done a great deal with Excel automation and have only called the GC two times for code, this being one of them. In regards to setting them to null and calling ReleaseComObject, note that I did so. So with that said (and no disrespect), I would love to see your solution to my code rather than tell me things I have done than mark my reply with a -1.

Comment: As I said above, this would best be done from within Excel and not be automated from .NET. Additionally, I don't think your code even does what the OP asked - - to find cells that have values in them. xlCellTypeLastCell is not guaranteed to do that. Can you explain what value adding GC.Collect to your solution provides that setting the Excel object references to null and calling ReleaseComObject doesn't already take care of?

Comment: Was not meant to be a complete answer, instead show how to get last used col for any row. GC.Collect is used as per my last paragraph in that reply and is used to release one stubborn object. I agree that working in Excel e.g. vba or macros is best but if requirements are firm to use automation then this is where this comes into play.

Comment: There are two issues that you haven't really addressed. 1) the use of GC.Collect in CallGarbageCollector method. It's entirely unnecessary because int results = eu.LastColumnForRow(fileName, sheetName,2); shouldn't be in a try/catch in the first place and thus no finally and the GC call would be needed. 2) the method you are using to determine the cells that have values in them will yield incorrect results when a cell had a vale and that value was then deleted.  The bottom line is that you are using a language constrcut (try/catch) incorrectly and you are using GC.Collect inappropriately.

Comment: Scott, perhaps if you tried this on your computer without the call to GC.Collect and all objects are completely disposed of then there is indeed something different between my computer and your computer as when I remove the call to GC.Collect Excel is still in memory for the call to LastColumnForRow. Solution is below for proof. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3D5A9A9A28080D1!892&authkey=!AHvgNJ6SjBjtzkQ&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: Karen, when I comment out eu.CallGarbageCollector(); and run your code and then shut down the application (by clicking the close button on the form), the Excel process ends (watching Task Manager while doing this). Also, your code does not do what the OP asks, which was "If I need to find out how many columns row 2 uses (How many contain data), how would I start." I take this to mean that the OP is not looking for the last column used, but how many columns in a row contain data. In total, I see unnecessary calls to GC, inappropriate use of try/catch and incorrect use of XML comments.

Comment: Scott, I know when closing the app that Excel is disposed but not until it's closed were my goal was to release objects before closing the app which means we looked at this differently. No I did not answer the question but instead give the OP an idea what it might take and that it's not the exact solution they want. The reason I placed it as an answer was because it was easier formatting-wise to do so then in a comment. I more use to Microsoft forums where a reply is not considered a answer or comment but simply a reply and that is how I treat it here.

Comment: There is no value in forcing Excel to stop while an application's who's sole purpose is to interact with Excel is running. The entire purpose for Microsoft making .NET memory management non-deterministic was to get the programmer out of the memory management business. Your approach is using the mentality of deterministic finalization, which doesn't buy you anything, but does result in more complex code that (by the way) brings the GC into the main thread, rather than a background thread, actually slowing the application down. There's really no justification for this.

Comment: Guess we see things differently :-)